# Can I make Django admin reflect a hierarchy of models?

Tags: django, model, navigation, django-admin, one-to-many

Assume a Django application with a few models connected by one-to-many relationships:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    ...

class Post(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    ...

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    ...
```

Conceptually, they form a hierarchy, a tree-like structure. I want the Django admin to reflect that. In particular:

1. in a changelist of posts, every post should have a link to the changelist of corresponding comments;
2. similarly, a post’s edit page should link to the changelist of comments from the top-right buttons area;
3. when I open that list of related comments, it needs to reflect the relationship in the breadcrumbs (something like: Posts › “Hello world” › Comments) and, ideally, also in the URL (`post/123/comment/`).

This should of course also apply to the other levels of the hierarchy.

Number 1 is pretty easy with a custom `list_display` entry and using the `?post__id=` query to the comments changelist. But this is little more than a hack. Generally Django assumes my three models to be independent, top-level entities.

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this? I guess I could override a bunch of templates and `AdminModel` methods, but perhaps there is a better solution for what seems like a common situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are not just looking at [Django Admin Inline Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) ?

There is no way that an automated admin will pick up your relationships, because in an RDBS there can be any number of foreign keys / one to one / many to many relations, and Django does not have a customized hierarchical behavior built in.

You can indeed edit the breadcrumb customizing an admin template if you want.

For relations you might also be interested into [django MPTT](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/) that allows to make hierarchical model instances. Also see this question: [Creating efficient database queries for hierarchical models (django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653000/creating-efficient-database-queries-for-hierarchical-models-django) in that respect.

Comment: @Vasili sorry I wrote my answer while you were writing your comment that definitely applies here too!

Comment: @vasiliy-faronov ...let me know if you need some more precise suggestions on what to touch in the admin!

Answer (score 0):

How is this a common situation? Consider the fact a model can have a virtually unlimited number of foreign key relationships, let alone visa versa. How would the admin 'know' how to represent this data the way a user requires without customizing things?

One would suggest you are used to work with content management systems rather than webframeworks (no pun intended). It's important to notice Django isn't a cms, but a webframework you can built on top of as you see fit. In a nutshell: 'Django is rather clueless and unaware of contextual requirements'.

Although the admin is quite a beast out-of-the-box, it *can* be hard to customize. There have been quite some discussions whether it should even be part of core. I can only suggest, if customizing things tends to get hacky, you should probably write your own 'admin', it's not that hard.

Comment: By “common” I meant “observed in a lot of real-world use cases”, not “the admin must handle this transparently”. Configuration—like specifying the foreign-key axis to traverse (in case there are many)—could be reduced to a couple of lines. And of course, I do not expect the admin to cater to my every whim—but there are ready-made solutions (often outside the core) for quite a few such whims. But here I guess the answer is “no”. I’ll wait for some more time before accepting.

Comment: Nobody suggested that the admin should know about this by itself. Django admin is highly customizable through subclassing, and adding in class fields.