# Python/Django recursion issue with saved querysets

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x, recursion, django-models

I have user profiles that are each assigned a manager. I thought using recursion would be a good way to query every employee at every level under a particular manager. The goal is, if the CEO were to sign in, he should be able to query everyone at the company - but If I sign on I can only see people in my immediate team and the people below them, etc. until you get to the low level employees.

However when I run the following:

```
def team_training_list(request):
 # pulls all training documents from training document model
 user = request.user
 manager_direct_team = Profile.objects.filter(manager=user)
 query = Profile.objects.filter(first_name='fake')
 trickle_team = manager_loop(manager_direct_team, query)
 # manager_trickle_team = manager_direct_team | trickle_team
 print(trickle_team)

def manager_loop(list, query):
 for member in list:
    user_instance = User.objects.get(username=member)
    has_team = Profile.objects.filter(manager=user_instance)
    if has_team:
        query = query | has_team
        manager_loop(has_team, query)

    else:
        continue

 return query
```

It only returns the last query that was run instead of the compiled queryset that I am trying to grow. I've tried placing 'return' before 'manager_loop(has_team, query) in order save the values but it also kills the loop at the first non-manager employee instead of continuing to the next employee.

I'm new to django so if there is an better way than recursion to pull the information that I need, I'd appreciate suggestions on that too.

EDIT:
As requested, here is the profile model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField( blank=True, help_text='Optional',)
    receive_email_notifications = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        blank=True,
        help_text='Optional'
    )
    carrier_options = (
        (None, ''),
        ('@txt.att.net', 'AT&T'),
        ('@messaging.sprintpcs.com', 'Sprint'),
        ('@tmomail.net', 'T-Mobile'),
        ('@vtext.com', 'Verizon'),
    )
    mobile_carrier = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=carrier_options, blank=True,
                                      help_text='Optional')

    receive_sms_notifications = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    job_title = models.ForeignKey(JobTitle, unique=False, null=True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, blank=True, related_name='+', null=True)
```

Comment: There is almost certainly an easier way to do this. If you show your models people can probably help draft a simpler query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it's a hierarchical model.

The problem with your current approach is this line:

```
query = query | has_team
```

This reassigns the local name `query` to a new queryset, but does not reassign the name in the caller. (Well, that's what I think it's trying to do - I am a little rusty but I don't think you can just `|` together querysets like that.) You'd also need something like:

```
query = manager_loop(has_team, query)
```

to propagate the changes via the returned object.

That said, while Django doesn't have built-in support for recursive queries, there are some third party packages that do. Old answers eg ([Django self-recursive foreignkey filter query for all childs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725343/django-self-recursive-foreignkey-filter-query-for-all-childs) and [Creating efficient database queries for hierarchical models (django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653000/creating-efficient-database-queries-for-hierarchical-models-django)) recommend django-mptt. Your tag mentions postgres, so this post might be relevant:
https://two-wrongs.com/fast-sql-for-inheritance-in-a-django-hierarchy

If you don't use a third-party approach, it should be possible to clean up the evolution of the queryset - cast it to a set and use `update` or something, since you're accumulating profiles. But the key error is not using the returned modified object.

Comment: Hi Peter, I modified the last line in the IF statement to "query = manager_loop(has_team, query)" and it worked! But I'm having trouble understanding the logic of assigning the queryset equal to the function itself.

Comment: You're not assigning the queryset to the function, you're assigning the queryset to the return value of the function. That's very standard Python for functions that return a new value, if it's not clear you might want to work through tutorials until it is. You'll see it all over the place.